# Are four non zero vectors are always linearly dependant

Tags: vectors

My book (cengage-JEE) says this is true.

I feel there are more conditions to be stated.

If three vectors are on the z-x plane and the fourth vector is not in this plane, the vectors would be linearly independent, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $3$ non-zero vectors are in the $z-x$ plane, one of the vector can be expressed as linear combination of the other two.

It is linearly dependent.

Comment: bad wording from my side, could you give it one more look?

Comment: yup, if $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are on the $z-x$ plane, then one of them can be expressed as linear combination of the other two, it is not linearly independent. The dimension of $z-x$ plane is $2$.

Comment: but the fourth vector that is not in the z-x plane can not be expressed as a linear combination of the others right? Linearly independent? Are you saying that the fourth vector does not have to be expressable as a combination of the others? super confused :(

Comment: the $4$-th vector doesn't matter. if you can find $a_1, a_2, a_3$ not all of them $0$ such that $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2+a_3v_3=0$, then of course we have  $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2+a_3v_3+0v_4=0$.

Comment: Oh! I get it now, tysm

Answer (score 3):

No, in general, four non-zero vectors are not always linearly dependant. For example, the vectors $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ are linearly independent.

However, in $\mathbb R^3$, it is indeed true that any set of four vectors is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

$\{v\}$ linearly dependent iff $v=0$

$\{v_1,v_2\}$ linearly dependent iff $v_1 , v_2$ lies on the same line.

$\{v_1,v_2,v_3 \}$ linearly dependent iff $v_1 , v_2$ lies on the same line or the same $2D $ plane.

Three vectors $\{v_1,v_2,v_3 \}$ lies on $x-z$ - plane means they are linearly dependent.

To span the $ x-z $ plane we need two linearly independent vectors say $v_1, v_2$ , then the third vectors $v_3$ doesn't contribute anything new to their spanning set.

$span(\{v_1,v_2,v_3 \})=span(\{v_1,v_2 \})$

Now, we know super set of a LD set is also linearly dependent , doesn't matter on your additional vectors whether it lies or not outside that plane, I mean it may be LI but you get the same result.